# UseSerilog program.cs dotnet run stuck in building

Tags: serilog, .net-5

When i UseSerilog in program.cs. And use f5 start new instance with iis express. it works fine and logs to database, but when i do dotnet run in cmd the message get stuck forever in "Building.." and nothing happens no errors or nothing.

I use WriteTo: MSSqlServer. If i change to WriteTo console it starts to works with dotnet run.

My code:

Program.cs:

```
 public class Program
    {
 
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                config.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "connectionStrings.json"),
                    optional: true,
                    reloadOnChange: true);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            }).UseSerilog((hostingContext, services, loggerConfiguration) =>
            {
                loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft"))
                    .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("System"));
            });
}

appsettings.json:
   "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "RSAnsokanData",
          "tableName": "Log",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I use .net 5.0

with

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" Version="5.6.0" />
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling [SelfLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) to see if there are any errors written by the MSSqlServer sink?

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete. Thanks for the tip but it did not write anything to the log anyways. I changed to:  .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.AddSerilog();
                }) And it started to work.

Answer (score 2):

My case was quite similar to [Sk Shahnawaz-ul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67795210/5759260)'s answer. I setup the logger using the `appsettings.ENVIRONMENT.json` file, like this:

```
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production";
Console.WriteLine($"Starting project on {environmentName}!");
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json")
    .Build();

var config = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration);
Log.Logger = config.CreateLogger();
```

By default, Serilog looks for a `"Serilog"` key in the JSON. The problem was that I started working on the project on another machine with a different environment name, but the `appsettings.newmachine.json` file didn't have the key. I copied it from the other machine's appsettings and now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. For me the root cause was that I was not passing the environment variable which I have used to set up Serilog's minimal logging configuration.

I edited the launchSettings.json file and for the profile having the setting:
`"commandName": "Project"`, included the environment variable and it worked.